# Why is ToString() not working on a type String , and what is the work around?

Tags: c#, string-conversion

I'm reading rows from excel into a model , and excel returns the input such as "10%" or "20%" as "0.1" ,"0.2" **string** . What is the best way to convert that string into a **string** such as "20%" , "10%" and to avoid unnecessary conversions, in order not to lose on the performance ? So just to clarify i need to convert string to a string but the program is not letting me obviously . I could convert that string to double then convert that double to string with `ToString("#0.##%")`, but I would like to know if there is a faster way .

This is the code that reads row and formats excel columns into model props types

```
static T ReadRow<T>(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int rowNum)
    {
        var o = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        int colNum = 1;
        foreach (var p in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (worksheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum].Value != null)
            {
                p.SetValue(o, Convert.ChangeType(worksheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum].Value, p.PropertyType));
            }
            colNum++;
        }
        return o;
```

Comment: What library are you using to read from Excel? Does it have methods to read a cell value as a specific data type?  If so, use those.

Comment: Could you show the code you use to *get* that "0.1" string value?

Comment: You expect there to be a string solution where you're effectively wanting to perform a *numeric* conversion? Converting to some numeric type (not necessarily double) is the *obvious* route to follow. First worry about correct. Then measure. Then, if your code isn't adequately performing identify the bottlenecks and then analyse those for performance issues. Don't start with "every piece of code has to run as fast as possible" because more often than not, it's not going to provide much benefit to your users.

Comment: Apart from @Bradley's comment, which correctly states that the library you use should have functions to return percentage columns as percentage strings, why do you think converting a number to a string incurs a performance hit? It is negligible, given you are reading an Excel file from disk and processing it.

Comment: @RenéVogt I was thinking the same thing, but it will only work for less than 100%... if the column can contain 110% this will be translated to `1.1` and obviously your suggestion will return the wrong result.

Comment: I added the code snipet for readRow , i'm using EEPLUS nugget package

Comment: I'll get banned again , cmon guys question was legit ...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If my model would say i need numeric , it would be numeric , but since i need string (varchar to db ) i obviously need it back as a string . This is not the start . This is the end .

Comment: @CodeCaster It's because , imagine pricelist with like 2000 products , and foreach of them i need to convert string 0.1 to double then that double to string . I just thought there is a better way that's all

Comment: You'll get banned if you start vandalizing your own question. The down-votes probably came because of the formatting of your question, which makes it hard to read.

Comment: @GeertBellekens its 1 min read paragraph . To much to ask ?

Comment: It's not the length, but the (lack of) formatting which makes it hard to read. If you want people to invest time to answer your question then you should invest in making the question as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what prachi has put with a solution to converting the string to your desired result.

```
string val = "0.2"; // for reference

string.Format("{0}%", Convert.ToDouble(val) * 100);
```

Comment: Your code returns 200% for 0.2 i think you would agree it's not valid , it's because of 0.2 rather then 0,2 . so it's ether * 10 , but then when value ,such as , 0.01 which should be 1% this code returns 10 ,(if *10)

Comment: No I stand by what I've written, basic math.  0.2 * 100 = 20 not 200.

Comment: sry dude , guess i should stop using this online compiler http://rextester.com/ since he gives false results ...

Comment: The problem is `Convert.ToDouble(val)` which will use the system-default culture. To *always* use `.` as a decimal separator, simply use `Convert.ToDouble(val, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. (Personally I'd use `double.Parse` instead, or better yet `decimal.Parse` as you're parsing a decimal value...)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting 10% as .01 is that the number is stored as .01 only and when reading excel you will get its actual stored value. You see it as 10% because its formatted as % in excel. 
To read the percent: 10% as string '10%' you will have to format the string when reading.